# New provider updates builder should be changed to create, getting errors

Tags: flutter, dart, builder, flutter-provider

Here I wrote two different tries for Products()- no arguments, but in debug it requires and for Orders(authToken, userId, orders)- and it does not work anyway

```dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Auth(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
          create: (_) => Products(),
          update: (_, auth, previousProducts) => previousProducts
              ..receiveToken1(auth, previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items),
        ),
        // ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
        //   builder: (ctx, auth, previousProducts) => Products(
        //     auth.token,
        //     auth.userId,
        //     previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items,
        //   ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Cart(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Orders>(
          create: (_) => Orders(authToken, userId, orders),
          update: (_, auth, previousOrders) => previousOrders
              ..receiveToken2(auth, previousOrders == null ? [] : previousOrders.orders),
        ),
        // ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Orders>(
        //   builder: (ctx, auth, previousOrders) => Orders(
        //     auth.token,
        //     auth.userId,
        //     previousOrders == null ? [] : previousOrders.orders,
        //   ),
        // ),
      ],
```

And here is my function in providers\products.dart, and it gives me error in _items = items - A value of type 'List' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List'.

```dart
class Products with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _items = [];
  // var _showFavoritesOnly = false;
  String authToken;
  String userId;
    
  Products(this.authToken, this.userId, this._items);
    
  List<Product> get items {
    // if (_showFavoritesOnly) {
    //   return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
    // }
    return [..._items];
  }
    
  List<Product> get favoriteItems {
    return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
  }
    
  Product findById(String id) {
    return _items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
  }
    
  void receiveToken1(Auth auth, List<Products> items) {
    authToken = auth.token;
    userId = auth.userId;
    _items = items;
  }
```

The same for Orders:

```dart
class Orders with ChangeNotifier {
  List<OrderItem> _orders = [];
  String authToken;
  String userId;
    
  Orders(this.authToken, this.userId, this._orders);
    
  List<OrderItem> get orders {
    return [..._orders];
  }

  void receiveToken2(Auth auth, List<Orders> orders) {
    authToken = auth.token;
    userId = auth.userId;
    _orders = orders;
  }
```

Error Stack:

[image]

Can you please help me find an error, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to set the type of object in the `List` to different objects than youve defined it as.

```
class Orders with ChangeNotifier {
  List<OrderItem> _orders = []; //<-----------Here you define type as OrderItem
  String authToken;
  String userId;
    
  Orders(this.authToken, this.userId, this._orders);
    
  List<OrderItem> get orders {
    return [..._orders];
  }

  void receiveToken2(Auth auth, List<Orders> orders) { //<--------------- List of Orders
    authToken = auth.token;
    userId = auth.userId;
    _orders = orders; // <---------------- Trying to set a list of OrderItem to list of Orders
  }
```

The same is the case with your `Product` except thats only a small typo

```
class Products with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _items = []; //<----------------- Product
  // var _showFavoritesOnly = false;
  String authToken;
  String userId;
    
  Products(this.authToken, this.userId, this._items);
    
    
  void receiveToken1(Auth auth, List<Products> items) { // <--------- Products
    authToken = auth.token;
    userId = auth.userId;
    _items = items;
  }
```

I cannot see your models so do not know which the correct one is. But once you have set them to be the same object you will fix the errors in your `Provider`'s

However I would assume with `Orders` you want

```
class Orders with ChangeNotifier {
 List<OrderItem> _orders = [];

 void receiveToken2(Auth auth, List<OrderItem> orders) {Orders
    authToken = auth.token;
    userId = auth.userId;
    _orders = orders;
 }
```

And with `Products`

```
class Products with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _items = []; 
    
    
  void receiveToken1(Auth auth, List<Product> items) {
    authToken = auth.token;
    userId = auth.userId;
    _items = items;
  }
```